# Ubuntu GUI not booting

Tags: gui

I have the following problem:

Old PC -> Tried to install Ubuntu via Live-CD (12.04 / 12.10) -> as soon as the desktop starts loading I get stuck at a black blank screen. No wallpaper, no GUI, no nothing. I cannot load a terminal via ctrl + alt + F1.

I tried installing Ubuntu Server (12.04) which worked fine. After installing I did a sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop which led to the exact same problem as with the Live-CDs.

I am clueless as to what is going wrong here. I used ubuntu on this PC before without problems.

Comment: Old PC ... maybe you aren't meeting the minimum requirements for the Unity desktop. You could try something lighter, like [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net). Newer versions of Ubuntu take more memory then older versions did. Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware) for minimum hardware requirements.

Comment: Try taking a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076) also.